# Reference request: about consistency of adding any amount Quine atoms to ZF-Reg.?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

It is known that we can add to ZF-Reg. any amount of Quine atoms (singletons that are elements of themselves), we can even add a proper class of them.

> When that result was first proved?

> Does it depend on forcing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the history of this result, but it is much easier than forcing and I imagine it probably was known by the 1940s if not earlier.  Basically, you can just formally construct a cumulative hierarchy starting with some collection of Quine atoms.

Here is one way to formalize the construction.  Let $(M,\epsilon)$ be a structure in the language of set theory.  We define an extension $M'$ of $M$ as follows.  Let $S$ be the set of all subsets of $M$ that are not the extension of any element of $M$.  We then define $M'=M\sqcup S$, with $\epsilon$ extended to say that additionally $m\mathbin{\epsilon}s$ when $m\in M, s\in S,$ and $m\in s$.

Now start with a structure $M_0$ consisting of some set of Quine atoms.  Recursively define $M_{\alpha+1}=M_\alpha'$ and let $M_\alpha$ be the direct limit of $M_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$ if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.  The direct limit of these structures $M_\alpha$ over all ordinals $\alpha$ is then easily verified to be a class model of ZF without regularity, with $M_0$ as its set of Quine atoms.  With a little care you can carry out a similar construction where the initial $M_0$ is a proper class to get a model with a proper class of Quine atoms (for instance, let $N_\alpha$ be the model constructed above starting from $M_0=\alpha$ and take the direct limit of the $N_\alpha$).

Comment: To my knowledge, that's due to Mostowski, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: Matti Rubin has some lecture notes on this: https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~matti/Axiomatic-ST-2012-08--Urelements.pdf and https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~matti/Axiomatic-ST-2012-09--Negation-of-Fnd-is-consistent.pdf are probably the right files. When he says "narrow to the left" he means "set-like".

Comment: The interpretation over the model you've built doesn't violate foundation, because when you extended $\epsilon$ all Quine atoms became empty, its actually a model of ZF-Extensionality. I don't see a clear argument about proving the unlimited property, that is we can have as many quine atoms as we may.  I think we need to start with a model of ZF, then blur some distinctions in a controlled manner between elements up to stage $V_\alpha$ as to get all of those elements in that stage being distinct quine atoms, something like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, the links are not working?

Comment: @Zuhair: Works just fine for me.

Comment: it says this site can't be reached?

Comment: @Zuhair: It might be that you're trying to connect to an Israeli server from a country that blocks such servers. If I had to hazard a guess, that's the one I'd make. If you have some proxy/paywall you might want to try that.

Comment: @Zuhair: When you extend $\epsilon$, the restriction of $\epsilon$ to $M$ stays the same; you just add new relations between $M$ and $S$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can reach to an answer to this question of mine. It can be easily seen in a labeled mereological interpretation of set theory.

Take any transitive model $M$ of ZFC. Define a new membership relation $``\epsilon"$ on elements of $M$ as:

$x \epsilon y \iff \exists z \in y : z=\{x\} $

Now we define *class* as a set of singletons.

Now $x$ is said to be a *pure class* if and only if $x$ is $\epsilon$-hereditarily "class", that is $x$ is a class and every element of the $\epsilon$ transitive closure of $x$, denoted by $T^\epsilon(x)$, is a class also

Define: $T^\epsilon(x)=\{m| \forall t [\forall y \epsilon x ( y \epsilon t) \land \forall z \forall k (z \epsilon t \land k \epsilon z \to k \epsilon t) \Rightarrow m \epsilon t]\}$

Let $S$ be the set of all pure classes in $M$; then clearly $\langle S, \epsilon \rangle $ is a model of ZFC.

If we want for example to have ZF-Ext.+ two distinct empty objects exist, then we define $S^*$ as the set of all sets in $M$ that are $\epsilon$-hereditarily $``class \ or \ \{\emptyset\}"$. Now clearly $\langle S^*, \epsilon \rangle$ would be a model of ZF-Ext. with only two distinct empty objects.

Now via a similar approach its easy to prove the existence of any amount of Quine atoms in ZF-Reg.

To do that, it's essential to recognize that sets that are not sets of singletons are regarded here as not classes and those would constitute the Ur-elements of our theory. And we can control how much we have of those in our universe of discourse.

For example we can allow all non classes but only up to some stage $V_\alpha$ to be in the $\epsilon$ transitive closures of our sets, that is we take a subset $S_\alpha$ of our model $M$, that is the set of all sets that are  $\epsilon$-hereditarily $``class \ \lor \in V_\alpha"$, [that is, non-classes that are not elements of $V_\alpha$ are shunned from being elements of the $\epsilon$-transitive closure of elements of $S_\alpha$]; define a new membership relation $\epsilon^*$ as:

$x \epsilon^* y \iff [class(y) \land x \epsilon y] \lor [\neg class(y) \land x=y]$

Then $\langle S_\alpha, \epsilon^* \rangle$ would be a model of ZF-Reg. with $|V_\alpha|$ many Quine atoms.

If we want a proper class of Quine atoms, then we define the above membership relation over the whole of our original model $M$ of ZFC.