# Can we have a set that is hereditarily equinumerous to itself, of any size?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Is it consistent to add to ZFC-Reg. the existence of a nonempty set $\mathcal H_\mathcal H$ that is hereditarily equinumerous to itself?

If that is consistent, then is it consistent that we can have $\mathcal H_\mathcal H$ being of any nonempty cardinality? Formally that is:

$\forall x (x \neq \emptyset \implies \exists y \forall z [z \in TC(\{y\}) \Rightarrow z \sim x])$

Where $``TC(x)"$ stands for "transitive closure of $x$" defined in the usual [manner](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Transitive_Closure_(Set_Theory)), and $`` z \sim x"$ stands for existence of a bijection between $z$ and $x$.

Comment: A set satisfying $x=\{x\}$, also called a quine atom, shows that the first question has a positive answer.

Comment: @tomasz, the second condition of mine is a flagrant violation of Aczel's anti-foundation axiom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and the proof is nearly identical to the argument in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3930634/86856): just start with an $M_0$ that consists of a set which is hereditarily of some size, and then formally construct a cumulative hierarchy on it.  Or, if you want to simultaneously get such hereditarily equinumerous sets of all cardinalities, take $M_0$ to be a class-sized structure which consists of such sets for all cardinalities.

More generally, that construction shows that given any structure $M_0$ in the language of set theory which satisfies extensionality, there is a class model of ZFC without regularity which contains a transitive set that is isomorphic to $M_0$.  This works even if $M_0$ is a proper class (take a direct limit of the construction over all set-sized substructures of $M_0$), as long as each element of $M_0$ has only a set of elements (this assumption is needed for Power Set to hold).

Comment: any nonempty cardinality means any cardinal larger than the empty set.

Comment: But how are you formulating that statement in the language of set theory?

Comment: OK, I'll add the formulation. thanks

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you meant *simultaneously* such a set exists for each cardinality.

Comment: Yes, I want it for all cardinalities. But regarding your answer, you simply took $M_0$ to be a set that is hereditarily of size $\kappa$, but my question is about the very existence of such sets. What is the proof that for example for $\aleph_1$ there can exist a set that is hereditarily of size $\aleph_1$ in the first place? I mean I know that if such a set can exist then one can iterate powers over it thereby building a hierarchy over it that would satisfy ZFC and its existence, but what's the proof that it can exist in the first place.

Comment: Just let $M_0$ be the set of finite sequences in $\omega_1$, for instance, with the membership relation $x\mathbin{\epsilon}y$ if $x$ is an extension of $y$ by one more term.

Comment: Nice! Marvelous!